# Realm count/indices not counting in ForEach

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui, realm

I'm trying to make a view where users can create their own collections, however it seems my ForEach always returns zero list indices BUT when I insert the .count into print its counting correctly, so append is working. How I can fix the cell loop? It was working with non-realm array...

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

final class TagGroup: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @objc dynamic var _id = ObjectId.generate()
    @objc dynamic var name : String?
    var tags = RealmSwift.List<Tag>()
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        "_id"
    }
}
```

...

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

struct CreateTags: View {    
    var tagGroup = TagGroup()

    var columns: [GridItem] =
        Array(repeating: .init(.flexible(), spacing: 8), count: 2)
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .trailing, spacing: 8) {
                    //this code should draw an rectangle for each tag in a list, but it does nothing
                    ForEach(tagGroup.tags.indices,  id: \.self) { tagIndex in
                        VStack {
                            ZStack {
                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemGray6))
                            }
                            .aspectRatio(1.5, contentMode: .fit)
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                    }
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            tagGroup.tags.append(Tag())
                        }) 
    ...
```

Comment: Please help us to help you but doing further troubleshooting. Add a breakpoint to your code and step through it line by line until something isn't right - perhaps a var is nil or a loop exits unexpectedly. Once you've isloated the issue, update the question with more info an we'll take a look. What are you expecting this `ForEach(indices,  id: \.self)` to do?

Comment: @Jay I am sorry, the code here was wrong as I was trying to solve the issue but it was even more bad.. Is it clean now?

Comment: Are you trying to print a list of the indices 1, 2, 3 etc? Or what is this `$inputName[tagIndex]`? Why this `inputName.append("")`?

Comment: Im not trying to print it , when I use print(tagGroup.tags.indices) it works and it prints lete say 0..<5, based on how many times I pressed the button, I just wanna know why its not working in ForEach - it always draws zero rectangles...  Removed the inputName from the snippet.